# silverstripe fluent locale configuration

Tags: silverstripe, fluent, silverstripe-4

I need help to understand the documentation for Fluent, from here [Fluent config documentation](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/configuration.md)

The documentation says: 
"You can create locales via the /admin/locales CMS section."

**When I create a locale, for example english, and then click on it I get at popup saying "Not Found". 
Do I need to install the locale somewhere else before using it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `dev/build?flush=1` when you installed the module? After installation you should have everything read to go, and can start adding locales in the CMS.

Note that when you add your first locale in the CMS, the existing pages you have will not be available in that locale and you'll need to go into the Pages section and publish the pages you want to show up in your default locale.

Comment: Yes, I have run dev/build?flush=1. So there is probably something wrong with my installation of fluent?

Comment: I've tested to install the most recent releases of fluent found here: https://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent but I still have the problem with "Not Found" message and no dropdown in the left hand menu in the CMS section. I'm using Silverstripe 4.1.1. Is fluent broken, or is it not compatible with my Silverstripe version?

Comment: I tested to make a clean installation of silverstripe with composer (version 4.2.1) and installed fluent. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this aswell.

The problem were missing files in the resouces folder. The 'Not found.' message in the admin panel refers to missing static assets like js and css files from the resouces folder. Open up your dev tools and inspect the 404'd requests. There you can see which files exactly are missing.